# jQuery: Hidden element shifts downward on hover out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

When my `AppBorder` element is hovered over, my hidden `AppMenu` appears on the right. But once I hover out, `AppMenu` does a quick drop below `AppBorder` before it disappears. How do I get rid of that weird after-effect so that `AppMenu` just disappears on hover out instead of plopping below my main element?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I just tried that but the menu still drops below `AppBorder` it just shifts it to the right within the dropped border.

Comment: @Michael Coker thanks for adding the ajax code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using CSS `:hover` to change the width of the parent, which doesn't fire at the same time as the the jquery that makes the strip on the right fade in and out completely. Will work fine fading in, but when you un-`:hover` the element, that immediately removes the new width before the strip on the right is fully removed, causing it to shift below since there isn't enough horizontal space for it to display to the right.

You don't need the widths though, you can just use `display: flex` (or I used `display: inline-flex` since you `float`ed that element originally) on the parent and they'll lay out side-by-side, and it seems to behave as expected.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.AppBorder').hover(function(){
  var menuId = $(this).attr('data-menuid');
  $('#'+menuId).stop(false, true).fadeToggle('fast');
 });
});
```

```css
.AppBorder {
 border: 1px solid #898989;
 display: inline-flex;
 margin: 10px 7px 10px 7px;
}
.AppBorder:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.AppImg {
 width: 70px;
 height:70px;
 margin: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}
#Text {
 width: 80px;
 height: 16px;
 float: left;
 font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.AppMenu {
 display: none;
}
.IconBorder, .Icon4Border {
 border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
 border-top: none;
 border-right: none;
  width:26px;
 height: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 4px 0px 2px 0px;
}
.Icon4Border {
 border-bottom: none;
}
.Icon {
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AppBorder" data-menuid="Menu1">
<div id="IconAndText">
 <div><img src="I/App1.png" class="AppImg"></div>
 <div id="Text">Text</div>
</div>
  
<div class="AppMenu" id="Menu1">
 <div class="IconBorder"><img src="#" class="Icon"></div>
 <div class="IconBorder"><img src="#" class="Icon"></div>
 <div class="IconBorder"><img src="#" class="Icon"></div>
 <div class="Icon4Border"><img src="#" class="Icon"></div>
</div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Ah so that's what the problem was. I didn't think it had anything to do with the timing of different codes, makes complete sense now. Really, thank you for the clear explanation and helping to fix the code. I'm grateful - thank you!

Comment: @confused5000 no problem :) If you wanted to do it with your existing code, you can add the width you're changing on `:hover` to a class instead, add that class to the element when you hover it, then use a callback in `$.fadeOut()` to remove the class *after the element fades out*. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evwyee But it's a lot cleaner and doesn't involve having to calculate widths or anything to just use the flex approach in my answer.

Comment: I think the first method you used is a lot more simpler. I'm not very good with Javascript/jQuery syntax, so reading your second method with the jQuery code is helping me out a lot. I appreciate you doing this, you are really doing a lot to help people - thank you very much!